# How to mark Specflow steps as 'Obsolete' to support progressive, backwards compatible refactoring

Tags: c#, refactoring, bdd, specflow

I'm currently refactoring a medium size application due to some terminology changes in the business terms. We have around 121 SpecFlow feature files that would need to be changed.

I like how you can "deprecate" an API in C#, first as warnings:

```
[Obsolete("Use MyClass.NewMethod instead")]
public void OldMethod() { }
```

Then compiler errors:

```
[Obsolete("Use MyClass.NewMethod instead", true)]
public void OldMethod() { }
```

It would be nice to have this sort of functionality for SpecFlow steps:

```
[When("I old foo", Obsolete = true)]
[When("I new foo")]
public void WhenIFoo() { }
```

**Is there any way to mark steps in SpecFlow as obsolete so other developers know the steps need to be changed in their Feature files, but not prevent them from authoring and running tests?** And as an added bonus, **Is there a way to optionally cause compiler or test run failures?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with [version v2.4](https://specflow.org/2018/specflow-2-4-released/), SpecFlow respects `[Obsolete]` attributes on step bindings.

For your example you would probably use it like this:

```
[When("I old foo")]
[Obsolete("you should use WhenIFoo instead")]
public void WhenIOldFoo() { }

[When("I new foo")]
public void WhenIFoo() { }
```

As the default behavior for using such steps a warning is issued. Utilizing the `obsoleteBehavior` attribute on SpecFlow's `<runtime>` configuration, you can change that, esp. failing test execution:

```xml
<specFlow>
    ...
    <runtime obsoleteBehavior="Error" />
</specFlow>
```

In the meantime the [Wiki-page for the Configuration](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Configuration#runtime) has been updated to document that feature.

Comment: Fantastic! It's funny. The pull request mentioned the issue I created for this exact problem. I actually have a need for this again.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a solution directly in SpecFlow, but I did Get It To Work™ using an extension method to the ScenarioContext:

Note: This uses MsTest, but I'm sure other unit testing frameworks have a way of marking tests as "pending" or inconclusive with a message.

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MyTestProject
{
    public static class ScenarioContextExtensions
    {
        public static void MarkStepObsolete(this ScenarioContext scenario, string newStep, params object[] newStepFormatArgs)
        {
            var message = string.Format(@"This step is obsolete. Use '" + scenario.CurrentScenarioBlock + " " + newStep + "' instead.", newStepFormatArgs);

            Assert.Inconclusive(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your step definitions you make the old steps "obsolete" and they show up as inconclusive tests which give you a hint to a replacement step:

```
[When(@"I click the ""(.*)"" anchor")]
public void WhenIClickTheAnchor(string anchorText)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.MarkStepObsolete(@"I click the ""{0}"" link", anchorText);
}

[When(@"I click the ""(.*)"" link")]
public void WhenIClickTheLink(string linkText)
{
    // ...
}
```

And it shows up in the Test Explorer panel:

> Assert.Inconclusive Failed - This step is obsolete. Use 'When I click the "Home" link' instead.

This at least tells other developers how to fix the new tests they were writing while I was changing the terminology in the existing scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to to do it with steps `Scopes`:

```
[When("I old foo", Scope(Tag = "Obsolete"))]
[When("I new foo")]
public void WhenIFoo() { }
```

Ensure the tag(its a regex) is unique because the idea is to not match any of the scenarios tagged.

What will happen is that your test will be marked as `Not Run` and more importantly the scenarios using this step will get a pink step **so it will be visible compile time.**

If you want to mark as obsolete the whole class then just simply tag the class as follows:

```
[Binding, Scope(Tag = "Obsolete")]
public class Steps
```

Reference:
https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Scoped-bindings#scoping-tips--tricks

Comment: I'll have to try this out. Looks promising.